# Xamarin Forms Shared Play Mp3 file on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, audiotrack, shared-project

I have asked this question in Xamarins forum but nobody has answered, im hoping this forum can provide an answer for me.

My problem is how to play an mp3 file from a shared project on android.

I'm making a Xamarin Forms project and uses interfaces to make platform specific code for playning tha mp3 file.

I have embedded 360 mp3 files in my shared project, and the pass the file to the interface to make the mp3 play.

The class AudioHelper returns a stream by getting the correct mp3 file based on it's name

```
var assembly = typeof(StaveApp_v2.App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
(resourcePrefix + $"Audio.{name}.mp3");
return stream;
```

Then I pass the stream to the Interface

```
var audioStream = AudioHelper.AudioFile("aften");
DependencyService.Get<IPlayWord>().Play(audioStream);
```

On windows the file plays as expected, but I’m having trouble getting the file to play on android. I'm using AudioTrack to play the sound (the sound should play 2 times). The app plays a scratchy sound 2 times with a duration matching the file length, but I can’t get it to play correctly.

This is the code im using

```
 var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                audio.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                var audioBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                var byteLenght = audioBytes.Length * sizeof(short);
 var audioTrack = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music,
                                                16000,
                                                ChannelOut.Mono,
                                                Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                                                byteLenght,
                                                AudioTrackMode.Static);

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        audioTrack.Write(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.Length);
                        audioTrack.Play();

                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException illEx)
                    {
                        Log.Debug("StaveApp", $"Unable to initialize audio exception {illEx.Message}");
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    audioTrack.Stop();
                    audioTrack.ReloadStaticData();
                }

                audioTrack.Release();
                audioTrack.Dispose();
```

I'm getting no errors in logcat and

Comment: Why do you use so hard approach? It's much easier to store mp3 in android resources and play it on android side

Comment: Hi Eugene

So i don't have to copy the 360 mp3 files to all 5 projects in the solution, but maybe i should try your approach in the android project, if this dosen't work